# Можно ли подписать приложение одновременно и релизным и отладочным ключами?

Tags: android

Я опубликовал приложение с ключом отладки SHA 1, затем попытался обновиться с релизным ключом. Консоль не принимает обновления,требует старый ключ. Неужели придётся делать копию проекта с релизным ключом и заново заливать в консоль? Можно ли подписать приложение одновременно и релизным и отладочным ключами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ответ на заголовок:**

Нет, это невозможно. Одно приложение - один ключ (сертификат для подписи).

**Ответ по сути проблемы:**

Невозможно выложить в маркет приложение с дебажным ключом - у него срок действия всего [365 дней](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#expdebug), а маркет принимает приложения, подписанные сертификатами со сроком действия не [менее 25 лет](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#generate-key).

Таким образом вы выложили таки не с дебажным ключом приложение, а с вполне себе релизным (по крайней мере у этого ключа срок действия 25+ лет).

Если вы не можете найти этот ключ то да - у вас проблема. Нерешаемая. Вам придётся создавать новое приложение в консоли с другим пакетом и новым ключом для подписи.

С другой стороны, вы, возможно, столкнулись с проблемой иного рода - выложили приложение с подписыванием `APK` файла на стороне гугла самим гуглом. (это с недавних пор продвигаемое гуглом решение, от коего можно отказаться только нажав много кнопок и которое нельзя отменить, единожды согласившись (для каждого приложения этот механизм включается отдельно)). Если это ваш случай, то не всё потеряно - для подписи приложения на вашей стороне используется не релизный сертификат, но ключ загрузки, который можно поменять, связавшись с тех. поддержкой гугла через консоль. Если это не ваш случай - то только новое приложение с новым пакетом и новым ключом подписи.

Comment: Приложение с аутентификацией Google.Контрольная сумма сертификатов SHA 1 у меня создана в  keytool не релизная и файл google-services.json добавлен в приложение с этой контрольной суммой. Приложение на эмуляторе работает корректно, а скачанное с маркета не проходит аутентификацию.

Comment: @RuslanChepizhko, если ваша проблема не в утере ключа а в том, что дебажный `Apk` авторизацию проходит, а релизный нет, то дело в том, что в `google-services.json` нет отпечатка релизного ключа. В этом случае его надо добавить в него (если в `FirebaseConsole` это делали то там, иначе - там откуда качали файл). После этого надо заново скачать  `google-services.json`, обновить его в проекте (лучше - копипастой содержимого, не заменой файла), собрать APK заново и обносить его в консоли разработчика.

Comment: А в google-services.json можно добавит и дебажный и релизный SHA 1?   Или сначала нужно удалить дебажный ключ?

Comment: @RuslanChepizhko, можно и тот и этот. И ещё сколько угодно. Ограничений нет

Comment: Всё стало на свои места. Спасибо!